React Native - Node installation via Brew damaged Expo
At begin, I was trying to create a React Native project via Expo Go. So I did npm i -g expo and npx create-expo-app myproject. But unfortunately when I try to npx expo start, I get an error saying that the Expo could not find the module metro-cache.
Regretfully, without trying to install it at first place, I tried to create my project without Expo Go by using React Native CLI. So I did brew install node and brew install watchman. But then I realized the process is quiet complicated and tedious so I tried to go back to Expo Go again.
But when I try to create the project again, now I get this error.

ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/21.7.3/lib'

I just want to fully reverse what I've done on brew install node so I can use Expo again. Thank you.

I got similar errors today when trying to generate a new react project after using brew to install node, and realized it was from the brew post-installation steps not following through. I followed the steps on this on this post and the issue resolved and I was able to create the project
